# how to update the number component in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
```

I want to update it so that each number component is incremented by 1:

```
['a2', 'a3', 'a4']
```

What would be the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? If they're always sequential just delete the first and append one based off the last entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your list keeps this form, this should do nicely:

```
for x in range(len(l)):
    l[x] = l[x][0] + str(int(l[x][1:]) + 1)
```

Works for any number, and if the "a" part is longer, adjust `l[x][**1**:]` to the length of your numberless string.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to use a '2d-list' (I don't know if this is the correct term in Python):

```
myList = [['a',1],['a',2],['a',3]...]
```

you would print the elements with `print(myList[n][0] + str(myList[n][1]))` where n = the element you want to print. To increment the 'number component' you would use `myList[n][1] += 1` if you want to increment it by 1.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work with example you provided:

```
import re
lst = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']

def increment(word):
    return re.findall('[a-z]+', word)[0] + str(int(re.findall('\d+', word)[0])+1)

print([increment(i) for i in lst])
#['a2', 'a3', 'a4']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code,

```
import re

lst = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
print map(lambda item:(item[0] + str(int(re.search(r'\d+', item).group())+1)), lst)
```

This code finds the integer value in each element of the list using regular expression and increments the integer value and concatenate with corresponding string value.

References:-

[Python map function](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map)

[Python lambda (Anonymous) Function](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk)

[Python regular expression - search method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search)